# El grid-auto-flow: row dense no me funciona

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando ejecutar la propiedad `grid-auto-flow:` en su atributo `row dense` para que las columnas ocupen los espacios que se me queden sin rellenar pero al implementarlo no resulta efecto alguno.

```css
.firstMain__section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(56, 61, 44, 0.199);
  justify-content: center;
  float: left;
}

.pre__section {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  /* grid: auto-flow dense 250px / 200px 1fr; */
  grid-auto-rows: 280px;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  place-content: stretch;
  gap: 30px;
  width: 99%;
  padding: 2%;
}
```

```html
<section class="firstMain__section">
  <div class="pre__section">
    <div class="container__section  hover">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio ducimus ullam debitis quibusdam deserunt, accusamus provident aut nisi illum libero officia ea harum voluptate, hic en im. Minima quos libero blanditiis?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container__section hover">
      <h2>Lenguajes y<br> Frameworks</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic commodi ad repellendus iusto, animi dicta cumque, exercitationem sint molestiae, nemo architecto in</p>
      <a class="btn__header">Conoce más</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container__section hover different">
      <h2>Works</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic commodi ad repellendus iusto, animi dicta cumque, exercitationem sint molestiae, nemo architecto in</p>
      <a class="btn__header">Conoce más</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container__section  hover">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio ducimus ullam debitis quibusdam deserunt, accusamus provident aut nisi illum libero officia ea harum voluptate, hic en im. Minima quos libero blanditiis?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container__section hover">
      <h2>Lenguajes y<br> Frameworks</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic commodi ad repellendus iusto, animi dicta cumque, exercitationem sint molestiae, nemo architecto in</p>
      <a class="btn__header">Conoce más</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container__section hover ">
      <h2>Works</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic commodi ad repellendus iusto, animi dicta cumque, exercitationem sint molestiae, nemo architecto in</p>
      <a class="btn__header">Conoce más</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container__section hover ">
      <h2>Works</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic commodi ad repellendus iusto, animi dicta cumque, exercitationem sint molestiae, nemo architecto in</p>
      <a class="btn__header">Conoce más</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Puedes [edit] tu pregunta e insertar un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) para poder crear un [repro].

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que he visto, tienes mal el `grid-auto-columns` prueba con `grid-template-columns` y debería funcionar

```
.pre__section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  /* grid: auto-flow dense 250px / 200px 1fr; */
  grid-auto-rows: 280px;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  place-content: stretch;
  gap: 30px;
  width: 99%;
  padding: 2%;
}
```

Las propiedades grid-template-* se utilizan para definir tanto la posición como el tamaño de las celdas de la cuadrícula, las propiedades grid-auto-* se utilizan sólo para definir el tamaño de las celdas de la cuadrícula.